# How to get the actual free memory with sysinfo

Tags: c++, linux

I am  using sysinfo to get memory information since I've read reading files from /proc might be unsafe.
According to http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2010/10/06/determining-free-memory-on-linux I have to include buffer and cache to get the actual free memory.
This is my code:

```
struct sysinfo info;

if (sysinfo(&info) != 0)
{
    return false;
}

unsigned long result = info.freeram * info.mem_unit;
result += info.freeswap * info.mem_unit;
result += info.bufferram * info.mem_unit;
```

Is this correct?

Comment: That seems correct, though I am left to wonder why would you include swap into your calculations? Albeit it is usable virtual memory, it's for all practical purposes not very usable as it is slow to access.

Comment: Because I have no control which memory will be used in the end anyway. I just need a limit to prevent the application from crashing. Or do you know a way of making sure that the process does not use the swap?